# Stop scrolling page, change tabs, continue with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just got a design and request to make tabs change when you scroll you mouse down.

So i have a page that has 5 sections before the one with the tabs, so when user gets to this section and continue with scrolling, it should change 6 tabs and after last tab it should continue with scrolling page down.

I did not found any plugin that can do this so far.

Comment: Have any code for us to look at? We are here to help you not do it for you.

Comment: That requires some serious custom javascript. Disable the right scrollbar and enable only the mousewheel scrolling. Test if you're on the tabs part, if so stop scrolling the page, start tabbing on mousewheel; if the last tab is active and the mousewheel continue, keep scrolling the page...

Comment: *I did not found any plugin that can do this so far*  .... That is just bad developing expecting that all the things you want are on already made plugins.

Comment: I will try to add some sample fiddle.
@DanielPinzon Common sense is to see if someone already did this instead of doing it from scratch itself, i dont see a point in your comment. If i do not find any solution i will have to do it myself.

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend spending some time learning and using scrollspy from bootstrap. With some creativity you could accomplish this quite easily.
Advantage is you leverage bootstraps brilliance including cross browser compatibility.

Here are two links:

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

[boostrap tut](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy_plugin.htm)